# How to view the streams of a department

Tags: php, laravel

I have a department that has many streams. How can I manage all the streams from a specific department?

For now I have a route for the departments:

```
Route::resource('/manage/department', 'DepartmentController');
```

The index controller for the department

```
public function index()
{
    $departments = Department::all();
    return view('admin.department.index', compact('departments'));
}
```

The index file looks like this:

```
@if($departments)
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Dept Code</th>
            <th>Name</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach($departments as $department)
          <tr>
            <td>{{ $department->dept_code }}</td>
            <td>{{ $department->name }}</td>
            <td><a class="btn-primary btn" href="#">Streams</a></td>
            <td><a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{route('department.edit', $department->id)}}">Edit</a></td>   
            <td>
                {!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE', 'action'=>['DepartmentController@destroy', $department->id]]) !!}

                    {!! Form::submit('Delete', ['class'=>'btn btn-danger']) !!}

                {!! Form::close() !!}
            </td>
          </tr>
        @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
@endif
```

Now, when I click under on the streams button, I want to be able to view all the streams of that particular department as well as add a new stream.

How can I achieve that?

How would my new route be in case I have to add a new one, how do I do in the controller?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to manage Streams related to a department and by managing i think you mean the CRUD operations , a clean way to do that is to define a sub-resource related to the department manager :

**Routes**

```
Route::group( [ 'prefix' => '/manage/department/{department_id}'], function ( Router $router ) {
    $router->resource( 'streams', 'StreamsController',['as'=>'department'] ); // here 'as' acts as a prefix for streams resource named routes
} );
```

Now you got a sub resource controller with a department_id as a required parameter in every method ( you should add it ) like this :

**StreamsController**

```
public function index($department_id){
   // here you list the streams of a certain department smth like 
    $streams = Stream::where('department_id',$department_id)->get();
    return view('admin.stream.index', compact('streams'));
}

public function create($department_id){
  // here you add your create view
}

public function store(Request $request , $department_id){
  // your post request 
}
```

Finally in your index file you can call the index method like this :

 **Index**

```
<td><a class="btn-primary btn" href="{{route('department.streams.index',[$department->id])}}">Streams</a></td>
```

Comment: I was having problems to implement your code but came up with a solution that is actually simpler with no extra routes needed. Take a look at my answer.
Appreciate the support though

Answer (score 0):

The answer is actually simpler than what I imagined.

I added this route to my index:

```
<td><a class="btn-primary btn" href="{{route('course.show', $department->id)}}">Courses</a></td>
```

Then in the show method of the streams controller I did this:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $department = Department::findOrFail($id);
    $courses = $department->courses;
    return view('admin.department.show', compact('courses'));
}
```

No extra routes have to be added because when I created the model it already came with the resources.